# Logged out mid answer

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, captcha

I was writing an answer on math.se just a few seconds ago. When I went to submit it, it showed an error, something along the lines of “Unable to submit answer. See reason above”. There was, in fact, no reason above. After trying it again to no avail I (thankfully) copied my answer content to my clipboard and reloaded the page, only for me to be shown as not being logged in! Not only that, when I went to log on I was asked to enter a captcha. Has this happened to anyone else? Is it a bug? Is it possible someone is trying to hack my account (haha)?

Comment: Something similar happened to me https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/114/462.